# NETSDK1201: For projects targeting .NET 8.0 and higher, specifying a RuntimeIdentifier will no longer produce a self contained app by default

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, maui, visual-studio-2022

After updating **Visual Studio 2022 Community** to version 17.8.0, Visual Studio is unable to select the right framework for executing The project.

I have a solution with 2 projects that must run under "Multiple Startup projects", Both projects (MAUI and WebApi) run on dotnet 7.0. I updated the Visual Studio to the latest version and now I am unable to run the projects. The visual studio executes the target file in the SDK/8.0.

I am looking for a way to overwrite this behavior, for example: instead of running the target file from the .net 8, it runs in .net 7. Or any other solution that could fix this issue.

```
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(251,5): warning NETSDK1201: For projects targeting .NET 8.0 and higher, specifying a RuntimeIdentifier will no longer produce a self contained app by default. To continue building self-contained apps, set the SelfContained property to true or use the --self-contained argument.
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(251,5): warning NETSDK1201: For projects targeting .NET 8.0 and higher, specifying a RuntimeIdentifier will no longer produce a self contained app by default. To continue building self-contained apps, set the SelfContained property to true or use the --self-contained argument.
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4911,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "C:\Users\marco\.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\Headers\GoogleUtilitiesComponents-umbrella.h" to "bin\Debug\net7.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\Headers\GoogleUtilitiesComponents-umbrella.h". Beginning retry 7 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'bin\Debug\net7.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\Headers\GoogleUtilitiesComponents-umbrella.h'.
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4911,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "C:\Users\marco\.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\PrivateHeaders\GULCCComponentContainerInternal.h" to "bin\Debug\net7.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\PrivateHeaders\GULCCComponentContainerInternal.h". Beginning retry 7 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'bin\Debug\net7.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\PrivateHeaders\GULCCComponentContainerInternal.h'.
```

Comment: You should be able to explicitly set SDK version via the `global.json`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json

Comment: @Serg thank you so much! In addition, I specify the version of the file using 
`{
  "version": "7.0.404"
}`

now I able to run multiple solutions with this setup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

After making changes defined **Original Answer**, I started to receive an error
"warning MSB3026: Could not copy [long path]\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.3\ to [LongPathToBin\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.3"

to solve that, we need to set windows to accept long paths

I run this command in PowerShell as an Admin

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

references:

[warning MSB3026](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell)

[global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json)

---

### Original Answer

Thanks to Serg who gave a great tip to fix my issue.

let's describe what I did:

I create a `global.json` file and include it in the same directory of my solution. I added the framework information I want to target by default (after the update to Visual Studio Community 17.8.0, the default .net framework becomes 8.0 instead of 7.0 of the latest version).
`global.json` file

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.404",
    "rollForward": "latestMinor"
  }
}
```

You need to reinstall the Maui workflow (if you are using MAUI)

Open the developer powershell window inside the Visual Studio (Ctrl+`) and execute the following command:

```
dotnet workload restore
```

Close the visual studio and delete the `.vs` folder in the same folder as your solution.

After that, I closed and reopened the visual studio and started multiple projects that finally worked!